# How to know the names of node attributes available? (Maya Python or MEL)

Tags: python, maya, mel

WHen i see code examples like this:

```
xform ( '{mesh}.vtx[{vertex}]'.format(mesh = blabla , vertex = blabla...) )
```

I wonder ... how do i find which attributes does my "mesh" or whatever object i'm working on?.

I see in the channel box that i have, for example, translate X in a transform node... but when i change it and see what the script editor says... it is translateX. It could be "tx" or "trX" or "transX" or whatever.

How do i find out what attributes names are available in a certain type of node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [`listAttr` command](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/listAttr.html) will list the names of all attributes and has several options for filtering (eg long names only, short names only, animatable, user-created, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the Maya official documentation, under Scripting -> Mel -> Attributes.
It says you can see the real long (translateX) and short (tx) names of the attributes by going to the Channel Box -> Edit -> Channel Names -> Short / Long / Nice

[Documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/index.html?url=files/Attributes_Attribute_names.htm,topicNumber=d30e791881)